# Server-side events tracking with GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm looking for a way to implement server-side event tracking and link it somehow with GTM. Need to say I don't have a lot of experience with both  and all my experience is from developer-side.

When I worked with Google Analytics only to do server-side events tracking, I simply used [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) they have.

But now it seems like just pushing events to GA is not enough to make GTM have any idea about this events. Or, at least, to have *proper* idea about the event.

But now the question is:

How should I notify GTM about events which is server-sided by nature in the right way? Is it possible it all?

As far as I understand, one can "push" data to "data layer" as they call it, but once again, this push can be done from client-side only. And I need to make it server-side.

Answer (score 2):

GTM is a client-side javascript injector. It does not have a server-side component (you could download the generated Javascript file and host in on your own server, and it would still work).

Since GTM is not a tracking tool there is usually not need to run it on the server side (if you want to send data to an external tool from your server it is usually easier to cut out the middle man).

So the only way to push serverside events to GTM would be to run a client on the server, e.g. a headless browser like phantomjs. That could load a page with the GTM code and you could automate it to execute javascript functions based on input from your server side application. While technically feasible this sounds like a horrible PITA.

Update: Google has announced a closed beta for server-side tracking, where you run a container in a cloud environment that then distributes the requests. Simo Ahava has a little info in his twitter feed: https://twitter.com/SimoAhava/status/1222459714614841346. This is not yet a production feature.

Comment: Yes, definitely don't want to go this way.

But let's say I want to track "payment successful" events with GTM, the only place where I'm sure that it was successful is the server-side. What the options? Still sounds weird for me that I can't track that properly.

Comment: GTM does not track, it merely inserts tracking code into a web page. On the server there is no web page, so you would use the measurement protocol and send the data directly to GA. If you are looking for a service to dispatch serverside events to multiple vendors then GTM will not be any help.

Comment: To expand on Eike comment, GTM is merly a switch board for dynamic injection of code. Thus, GTM only conveys the information through to Google Analytics. So, GTM does not need to have any idea about your events.

Comment: GTM tends to be blocked by many AdBlockers while GA is not. This creates a terrible situation where 50% of your traffic and events may never be tracked. I was trying to find away to at least manually pushEvent but if GTM does not support that then the only way is to fallback to GA. The problem with GA is that it is GA only, you cannot capture the event and do other things like GTM does which can also send the events to other services.